# How do I keep responsive iframe within a flexbox layout?

Tags: html, css, iframe, flexbox

I have a flexbox layout that contains the iframe in it. When I use `display: flex;` on the parent div, it doesn't display the iframe. When I remove the flex property from the parent div, it display it. I want to be able to keep the flexbox properties whilst having iframe responsive as a child element. How do I resolve this issue?

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheAmazingKnight/d71sv09o/).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="embed-div">
    <div class="embed-container">
      <iframe width="552" height="280" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EngW7tLk6R8?modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content-container">
    <p>Marzipan topping liquorice candy chocolate. Carrot cake donut candy canes marshmallow muffin cookie jujubes shortbread cheesecake. Chocolate bar powder danish donut croissant. Cotton candy tootsie roll apple pie sesame</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  /* removing this shows iframe, want ot keep this flexbox whilst showing iframe scaling */
  flex-direction: row;
}

.main-container .embed-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 52.25%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main-container .embed-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you made a mistake in your css file, you don't have to make a position absolute in side flexbox child

**CSS**

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  /* removing this shows iframe, want ot keep this flexbox whilst showing iframe scaling */
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;

}

.main-container .embed-container {
  padding-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 52.25%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .main-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="embed-div">
    <div class="embed-container">
      <iframe width="552" height="280" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EngW7tLk6R8?modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content-container">
      <p>Marzipan topping liquorice candy chocolate. Carrot cake donut candy canes marshmallow muffin cookie jujubes shortbread cheesecake. Chocolate bar powder danish donut croissant. Cotton candy tootsie roll apple pie sesame</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked! NOTE: The `.main-container .embed-container iframe {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}` had to be added back in for smaller screens when `flex-direction: column` to keep the thumbnail picture view intact.